# I am using multiple forms, in Slick Slider, which opens up in modal. I need ideas to achieve client side validation

Tags: jquery, reactjs, meteor, jquery-validate, react-component

I have to submit all forms together, so validation has to be returned on all fields of all forms. I tried to bind validate() [from jquery-validation] on componentDidMount() with all forms. But that doesn't work, and I don't have any errors either.

I am amateur to this technology, would love to hear from experts.

```
// from validate.js

import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-validation';

export default (form, options) => $(form).validate(options);  

// my modal component:

  componentDidMount() {
    const component = this
    for (const key in component.forms) {
      if (component.forms.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const form = component.forms[key]

        switch (form.id) {
          case 'form_1':
            validate(form, {
              rules: {
                name: {
                  required: true,
                },
              },
              messages: {
                name: {
                  required: 'Ico name is required!',
                },
              }
            })
          break

          case 'form_2':
            validate(form, {
              rules: {
                website: {
                  required: true,
                },
                description: {
                  required: true,
                },
              },
              messages: {
                website: {
                  required: "Please share ico's website",
                },
                description: {
                  required: 'Please provide a short description',
                },
              }
            })
            break

          default:
            break
        }        
      }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Can you add some of your code what you tried and what the exact errors were and what you expected the code should do?

Comment: Didn't have any error, what I wanted was error on validation failure.

Comment: You could validate against SimpleSchema, that would be an easy approach but this is rather an opinion. How did you configure jQuery validate to know what the expected valid form should look like?

Comment: I had started building this app from https://cleverbeagle.com/pup , So you see here sample. What I am trying to achieve is, client side validation.

Answer (score 0):

`.validate()` is the **initialization** method of the plugin and you would not use it inside of a `switch`.

Trigger `.validate({[options]})` inside of your document ready function.  Use `.valid()` inside of the `switch`.  The `.valid()` method is how you would programmatically trigger validation.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up, making my own error handling components, which would be triggered based on state changes, state update was triggered at `onChange` of form fields with failing validation.